# OpenAI API Unsupported Media Type (415 error)

Tags: file-upload, axios, openai-api, chatgpt-api, chatgpt-plugin

** I am working on a custom chatbot using OPEN AI's APIs.I am trying to upload a file to OPEN AI api servers  This is the endpoint I am using to post the upload request. Endpoint: https://api.openai.com/v1/files. I am getting this error: Error getting completion: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 415. **

```
`
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();


  const postFile = async () => {
    try {
      const requestBody = {
        file: file,
        purpose: "fine-tune"
      };

      const fileResponse = await axios.post(
        "https://api.openai.com/v1/files",
        requestBody,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${REACT_API_KEY}`
          }
        }
      );
      console.log("file is", fileResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error getting completion:", error);
    }
  };

  console.log("file", file);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="input-area">
        <input
          type="file"
          // value={file} this is commented
          onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
        />
        <button onClick={postFile}>Send File</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```